# nested Async not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am new to node js and I am trying to use async module to eliminate the setTimeouts. Here I am facing a problem. It is not working as expected. It calls the second function even before the first function completes execution. I searched for answers and tried multiple ways. But it doesn't seem to work. It prints "Inside db insert in async series" even before the async.forEach finishes. Can anyone please check the code and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    async.series([function(callback1) {
                console.log("Inside async series");
                try {
                    var msg = "";
                    var datas = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < service_name.length; i++) {
                        console.log("Inside for loop service names");
                        var child = {
                            "space_guid": space_guid,
                            "name": service_name[i],
                            "service_plan_guid": service_plan_guid[i]
                        };
                        datas.push(child);
                        console.log("datas array===" + JSON.stringify(datas))
                    }
                    async.forEach(datas, function(data1, callback) {

                        console.log("Inside async task");
                        var data = JSON.stringify(data1);
                        console.log("data value===" + JSON.stringify(data));
                        var options = {
                            host: 'api.ng.bluemix.net',
                            path: '/v2/service_instances' +
                                '?accepts_incomplete=true',
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': full_token_new
                            }

                        };
                        console.log("options is" + JSON.stringify(options));
                        var reqst = http.request(options, function(res) {
                            console.log("Sent for request");
                            res.setEncoding('utf8');
                            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                                msg += chunk;

                            });
                            res.on('end', function() {
                                try {
                                    console.log("message =======", msg);
                                    console.log("-----------------------------------------");
                                    msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
                                    msg1 = JSON.parse(msg);
                                    console.log("printing msg--" + msg1);
                                    console.log("-----------------------------------------");
                                    console.log("here i am", i);
                                    console.log(service_name.length - 1);
                                    callback();

                                } catch (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }

                            });
                        });
                        reqst.on('error', function(e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        });
                        reqst.write(data);
                        reqst.end();

                    }, function(err) {

                        console.log("for each error" + err);


                    });
                    callback1(null, null);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

            },
            function(callback1) {
                console.log("Inside db insert in async series")
                db_insert(service_name, solnName, full_token_new, uname, version);
                callback1(null, null);

            }
        ],
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("There's an error" + err);
            } else {
                console.log("result of async", results);
            }
        })
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Do not mix `try...catch` with async function, it will not work as you expect it.

Comment: Take `callback1(null, null);` in *try* block and place it in last function of async.forEach just bellow `console.log("for each error" + err);`

Comment: Use `async.each` instead `async.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `try...catch` with asynchronous code, this is bad practice and almost impossible to do right.

Also, your error stem from the fact you are calling `callback` just after `async.forEach`, which don't finish, and go to the next step.

Also, what do you mean by "eliminate the timeout"? Your whole code is in it, you can remove it whenever you want.

```
'use strict';

async.series([
    (callback) => {
        let msg = "",
            datas = [],
            i = 0;
        while(i < service_name.length) {
            let child = {
                "space_guid": space_guid,
                "name": service_name[i],
                "service_plan_guid": service_plan_guid[i]
            };
            datas.push(child);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        async.forEach(datas, (data1, callback) => {
            let data = JSON.stringify(data1),
                options = {
                    host: 'api.ng.bluemix.net',
                    path: '/v2/service_instances?accepts_incomplete=true',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': full_token_new
                    }
                },
                reqst = http.request(options, (res) => {
                    res.setEncoding('utf8');
                    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        msg += chunk;
                    });
                    res.on('end', () => {
                        msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
                        msg1 = JSON.parse(msg);
                        callback();
                    });
                });
            reqst.on('error', (error) => {
                callback(error);
            });
            reqst.write(data);
            reqst.end();
        }, (error) => {
            callback(error);
        });
    },
    (callback) => {
        db_insert(service_name, solnName, full_token_new, uname, version);
        callback();
    }
],
(error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("There's an error" + error);
    } else {
        console.log("result of async", results);
    }
});
```

Since this smell heavily like a `plssendzecode` question, I've removed every `console.log` and gone ES6 to make sure you will not be able to use it as such and need to read the change I made.

Comment: i meant i have eliminated many settimeouts by using async. Also I removed the try catch and placed the callback1 in function(err). Still it didn't work out :(

Answer (score 0):

I simplify code a little. 
`datas` and `processData` aren't good names.

```
setTimeout(onTimer, 3000);

function onTimer() {
    var datas = service_name.map(function(name, i) {
        return {
            space_guid: space_guid,
            name: name,
            service_plan_guid: service_plan_guid[i]
        }
    });

    function processData(data, callback) {
        var options = {
            host: 'api.ng.bluemix.net',
            path: '/v2/service_instances?accepts_incomplete=true',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': full_token_new
            }
        };

        var reqst = http.request(options, function(res) {
            var msg = '';
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                msg += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                try {
                    msg = JSON.parse(msg);
                    callback(null, msg);
                } catch (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
            });
        });

        reqst.on('error', callback);
        reqst.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        reqst.end();
    }

    async.map(datas, processData, function(err, results) {
        if (err);
            return console.log(err);
        // process msg of each request db_insert(...);  
    });
};
```